# Revise code that increases the length of a square?

Tags: java, methods

This code contains some logical errors but I'm having problems spotting them and changing the code based on these logical errors

```
public class square {
    private int sideLength; 
    private int area;

    public square( int initialLength ) {
        sideLength = initialLength;
        area = sideLength * sideLength; 
    }

    public int area() {
        return area;
    }

    public void grow() { 
        sideLength = 2 * sideLength;
    }
}
```

The program is supposed to calculate the area based on the side lengths and then grow the square. It doubles the side lengths. Will the area change with the new size in the way I have it set up now? Any other logical errors?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Why would you think the area (calculated when the square is initially constructed) would change without explicit code to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Things don't happen in a program unless you have programmed them. You have two options. The first one is that you always assign `sideLength` and `area` at the same time. Since you don't want code duplication, and since you cannot invoke the constructor again, it's best to do that in a separate method:

```
public class Square {
    private int sideLength;
    private int area;

    public Square(int initialLength) {
        setSideLength(initialLength);
    }

    // Separate method to update sideLength and area together.
    private void setSideLength(int sideLength) {
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
        this.area = sideLength * sideLength;
    }

    public void grow() {
        setSideLength(2 * sideLength);
    }
```

The second option is the always calculate the area on-demand without storing it. Since the calculation is simple and fast, this is a good option:

```
public class Square {
    private int sideLength;

    public Square(int initialLength) {
        this.sideLength = initialLength;
    }

    public void grow() {
        sideLength *= 2;
    }

    // Calculate area on-demand
    public int area() {
        return sideLength * sideLength;
    }
}
```